# Multiple requests single response synchronization

Tags: c, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

This seems like it should be a well known problem, but I haven't been able to find a good solution for it (neither from my brain nor the internet).

First, let's take a very simple example:

```
mutex request  <-- init to 0
mutex response <-- init to 0

Service thread (Guy S):
    while not finished
        wait(request)
        do stuff
        signal(response)

Someone requestion service (Guy U):
    signal(request)
    wait(response)
    do stuff with results
```

So far so good. `U` (user) signals `S` (service), and waits for its response. Everything is good.

Now imagine if there were many users, requesting the same service. Now the nature of the service is such that the results vary in time (more precisely periodically). Therefore, if 10 users ask for the service *more or less* at the same time, the service can safely only run once.

The first thing that comes to mind is this:

```
Guy S:
    while not finished
        wait(request)
        do stuff
        trywait(request)
        broadcast(response)

Guy U:
    signal(request)
    wait(response)
    do stuff with results
```

The different here being that, first `S` `trywait`s on request effectively setting it to 0 and therefore if many people have signalled it, only one of the requests would go through. Of course the mutex has a cap of 1, so all the extra signals accumulate to 1, which would be removed by the `trywait`. Second change is that, `S` would `broadcast` the response so all the `U`s would be unblocked.

Looks good at first glance, but there is a problem with it. Imagine the following sequence of executions:

```
Guy S:              Guy U1:              Guy U2:
wait(request)
                    signal(request)
working
                                         signal(request)
                    wait(response)
working
trywait(request)
broadcast(response)
                                         wait(response)
                    working
(loop)
```

If you look closely, `U2` is blocked unless someone sends a request again (god knows when in the future). Very bad.

Even with a single user, this can happen:

```
Guy S:              Guy U:
wait(request)
                    signal(request)
working
trywait(request)
broadcast(response)
                    wait(response)
(loop)
```

Can anyone come up with a good idea, or direct me to a known algorithm?

---

Additional info:

- `S` only periodically has new data to offer, but based on the application, the user may decide to get the data sporadically (through requests) rather than periodically. If the user requests too fast, I make him wait for the next period, so this it not an issue.
- I have access to readers-writer locks, conditional variables, semaphores and mutexes. Readers-writer looked promising for the response lock, but it would still be unclear when all the users have passed their `wait(response)` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with the following solution. Having `request` and `response` as semaphores:

```
Service thread (Guy S):
    while not finished
        wait(request)
        do stuff
        users_waiting = 1
        while (trywait(request))
            ++users_waiting
        for i = 0 to users_waiting
            signal(response)

Someone requestion service (Guy U):
    signal(request)
    wait(response)
    do stuff with results
```

I have to admit it is not perfect. Consider the following execution:

```
Guy S                Guy U1                Guy U2                Guy U3
Cycle 1:
wait(request)
                     signal(request)
                     wait(response)
do stuff
                                           signal(request)
trywait(request)
signal(response)
signal(response)
                     working                                            
                                                                 signal(request)
                                                                 wait(response)
                                                                 working
                                           wait(response)
Cycle 2:
wait(request)
do stuff
signal(response)
                                           working
```

As you can see, in such a case, user 3 can "hijack" response of user 2. There would be no deadlock or anything, except user2 would stay blocked more than it deserves.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem description, the issue is that, sometimes, the Service doesn't actually need to do anything to compute a new result, but can just "reuse" previous results.   (I see that you don't have the Service do anything until a request is made, so we don't have to worry about it having to update things independently of requests.)  If that is the case, could you modify the original Service like so:

```
Service thread (Guy S):
    while not finished
        wait(request)
        If stuff needs to be re done
            do stuff
        signal(response)
```

Comment: The part of `If stuff needs to be redone` is already there. I had removed it for simplicity. The problem is, consider two users: the both signal(request), and service wakes up, does some stuff and signals(response). With that signal, only one of the users would wake up, the other starving. I could use semaphores instead of mutexes, which then this code (as my original code also) would both work, except in reality "stuff needs to be redone" is not so clear (in my application)

Comment: My aim was to get something like this: "If in the middle of servicing one request, another comes, signal both of them in the end because both of them would be served by the same result. If not, whenever the next one comes serve it." Although I said the task is periodic in nature, that's was not entirely true. I have two types of services, one of which IS periodic in nature and I can easily determine "if stuff needs to be redone". The other one is extensions by users, having whatever functionality that I cannot predict.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I was assuming semaphores; my bad.  And (obviously) you understand the context better than I, but if the result is different if another consumer hasn't quite finished his request (as opposed to having just finished it), and there is no other criteria for determining the result, that seems a bit off.  For example, if the Service kept a record of WHEN the last request was processed, and any new requests that came in within a certain window got the same result, would be easy enough to implement.

Comment: What you say is true, but let me explain a bit more. The service here is a thread that makes a local copy of a shared memory that is periodically filled with new data from some sensors. Each application may decide to read these data at different rates (for example one periodic, but the other sporadic). I have two options with sporadic: each request updates only if there is something to update, otherwise, 1) returns. 2) blocks until there is new data. I have opted the 2nd method because then a user can request in a loop and safely get unblocked only when there is new data.

Comment: With your method, it is unclear whether "it's a second user who requested at the same time, so should just return", or "it's the same user who has requested again and must block until new results come"

Comment: @shahbaz: If there is no reliable way to tell where a request comes from, then there is no way to make the distinction you want.  If a request comes while another is being processed, then you know it is from a different user, but if not, it could be a repeat request or a new user.  I assume the service will always yield the latest info; the question is whether or not to unblock a particular user.  Which is a problem, as you don't get to choose which user gets woken up by a signal on a semaphore used by multiple processes.

Comment: I finally came up with a non-that-perfect solution using semaphores that I posted below. If you are interested, take a look